# How to have time control in Tableau filter multiple worksheets on Dashboard?

Tags: tableau-api

I have a dashboard in Tableau with two worksheets added. Right now Worksheet #1 has Filter #1 added for Field #1. Now that I’m adding Worksheet #2 with Field #2 (from a new table) to that dashboard, I’m uncertain how to use the **same** Filter #1 to restrict the time range for Field #2 and everything else on the dashboard.

To be clearer on my problem, here is my linkage in my data source I'm struggling with

```
Table #1.UserID <-> Table #2.User ID
Table #1.UserInsertedAt (Not linkable) Table #2.PetInsertedAt
```

Though the two tables are linked, the fields I want to filter by are two unlinkable fields (because user inserted at date is not correlated with when their pet was inserted at, just that the pet belongs to a specific user).

How can I apply the MONTH(User Inserted At) to the same control of MONTH(Pet Inserted At)? This would allow the viewer to slide the control and see users and, separately, pets added in this time range.

Right now tableau is: filtering for distinct pets for users added within control time range

But I actually want: filtering for distinct pets for pets added within the time range (separate of when the user was inserted)

Update: I've found a path forward but haven't perfected it yet. I need to most likely create a param that is a filter on both workbooks. What I'm still missing is how to make my separate Start Date and End Date param into one to-from date range between the two, and for that range to default when opening the dashboard to a range only showing this month before user adjusts.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is the same data source you can set the filter to apply to multiple sheets.

[image]

If you want this filter to restrict other filter's selections, then set this one to "Add to Context".

Comment: Hey Bernardo, thanks for you answer. I updated with more details if you can review. It seems with your solution it is filtering the datasource by MONTH(User Inserted At) when I really want the single control to filter MONTH(User Inserted At) for Workbook #1 and separately MONTH(Pet Inserted At) for Workbook #2 on the same dashboard.

Comment: If you can link to sample workbook with fake data in the same structure, that would be more helpful. When you say table 1 and 2 are linked, is there one data source or two and you're using data blending?

Comment: There's one data source with a Users table and a Pets table linked by User ID (A User can own multiple pets). The users table has a user insertion time and the pets table has a pets insertion time. I want to toggle the date filter on the dashboard and see users inserted in this time range as one metric and separately pets inserted as a separate metric. Hope that makes sense, but I'll try to go find sample data that can recreate it.

Comment: Hey Bernardo. I've been working on this diligently trying to figure out a solution. Gave an update above on a potential approach (using parameters) I'm about halfway to solving. Any tips on how to finish up this approach would be awesome. I wish there was an all-inclusive tutorial video on what I'm looking for but haven't found one yet. I just need to better leverage a Start Date/End Date set of params as a range that defaults on this month.

Comment: I'd make two data param, Start and End. It won't be like the range in your same but you can set default values to each.